# plotly displot rug text not showing

Tags: plotly

I am trying to customize the rug text on my ff.distplot (see Customize Rug Text, Colors & Title section of plotly distplot documentation: https://plotly.com/python/distplot/) and cannot figure out why the text (i.e. the name of the skill) isn't showing up?!?! Right now, only the encoded skill is included with the label.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the plot:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

colors = ["#333F44", "#37AA9C"]

fig = ff.create_distplot(
    [
        np.array(sample_df["machine learning engineer"]),
        np.array(sample_df["python developer"]),
    ],
    sample_df.columns,
    show_hist=False,
    rug_text=rug_text,
    colors=colors,
)

# add title
fig.update_layout(title_text="DistPlot")
fig.show()
```

Here is my sample_df:

```
{'machine learning engineer': {0: 46.0, 1: 46.0, 2: 46.0, 3: 46.0, 4: 46.0, 5: 46.0, 6: 46.0, 7: 46.0, 8: 46.0, 9: 46.0, 10: 46.0, 11: 46.0, 12: 46.0, 13: 46.0, 14: 46.0, 15: 46.0, 16: 46.0, 17: 46.0, 18: 46.0, 19: 78.0, 20: 78.0, 21: 78.0, 22: 78.0, 23: 78.0, 24: 78.0, 25: 78.0, 26: 78.0, 27: 78.0, 28: 78.0, 29: 78.0, 30: 78.0, 31: 78.0, 32: 78.0, 33: 78.0, 34: 78.0, 35: 78.0, 36: 78.0, 37: 12.0, 38: 12.0, 39: 12.0, 40: 12.0, 41: 12.0, 42: 12.0, 43: 12.0, 44: 12.0, 45: 12.0, 46: 12.0, 47: 12.0, 48: 12.0, 49: 12.0, 50: 12.0, 51: 93.0, 52: 93.0, 53: 93.0, 54: 93.0, 55: 93.0, 56: 93.0, 57: 93.0, 58: 93.0, 59: 93.0, 60: 93.0, 61: 93.0, 62: 93.0, 63: 93.0, 64: 93.0, 65: 42.0, 66: 42.0, 67: 42.0, 68: 42.0, 69: 42.0, 70: 42.0, 71: 42.0, 72: 42.0, 73: 42.0, 74: 42.0, 75: 42.0, 76: 50.0, 77: 50.0, 78: 50.0, 79: 50.0, 80: 50.0, 81: 50.0, 82: 50.0, 83: 50.0, 84: 50.0, 85: 94.0, 86: 94.0, 87: 94.0, 88: 94.0, 89: 94.0, 90: 94.0, 91: 94.0, 92: 59.0, 93: 59.0}, 'python developer': {0: 46.0, 1: 46.0, 2: 46.0, 3: 46.0, 4: 46.0, 5: 46.0, 6: 46.0, 7: 46.0, 8: 46.0, 9: 46.0, 10: 46.0, 11: 46.0, 12: 46.0, 13: 46.0, 14: 46.0, 15: 46.0, 16: 46.0, 17: 46.0, 18: 12.0, 19: 12.0, 20: 12.0, 21: 12.0, 22: 12.0, 23: 12.0, 24: 12.0, 25: 12.0, 26: 12.0, 27: 12.0, 28: 12.0, 29: 12.0, 30: 12.0, 31: 12.0, 32: 12.0, 33: 62.0, 34: 62.0, 35: 62.0, 36: 62.0, 37: 62.0, 38: 62.0, 39: 62.0, 40: 62.0, 41: 62.0, 42: 62.0, 43: 62.0, 44: 83.0, 45: 83.0, 46: 83.0, 47: 83.0, 48: 83.0, 49: 83.0, 50: 83.0, 51: 83.0, 52: 83.0, 53: 88.0, 54: 88.0, 55: 88.0, 56: 88.0, 57: 88.0, 58: 88.0, 59: 88.0, 60: 88.0, 61: 88.0, 62: 42.0, 63: 42.0, 64: 42.0, 65: 42.0, 66: 42.0, 67: 42.0, 68: 42.0, 69: 42.0, 70: 55.0, 71: 55.0, 72: 55.0, 73: 55.0, 74: 55.0, 75: 55.0, 76: 60.0, 77: 60.0, 78: 60.0, 79: 60.0, 80: 60.0, 81: 60.0, 82: 0.0, 83: 0.0, 84: 0.0, 85: 0.0, 86: 0.0, 87: 19.0, 88: 19.0, 89: 19.0, 90: 19.0, 91: 19.0, 92: 50.0, 93: 50.0}}
```

And here is the rug_text:

```
[['REST',
  'Linux',
  'Test-driven Development (TDD)',
  'PostgreSQL',
  'Python',
  'Flask',
  'JavaScript',
  'jQuery',
  'Django',
  'MySQL',
  'Git'],
 ['Linux',
  'PostgreSQL',
  'Python',
  'Flask',
  'Object-oriented Programming (OOP)',
  'Machine Learning',
  'Data Science',
  'Apache Spark']]
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `rug_text` shape doesn't correspond with your data.

You need to map a `rug_text` value for each data point.

Comment: That's a good thought but I've double checked (and just checked again) that there is in fact a rug_text value that corresponds to each rug tick. The top rug contains 11 points and the bottom has 8 and you'll notice the list of lists I posted is of length 11 and then 8.

Comment: Your sample_df has 94 rows, so you would need 94 rug text values for the top and 94 for the bottom.

Comment: Because there are a lot of duplicate values in `sample_value` you don't see as many ticks in the plot. However you still need to map each label to each data point.

Comment: ohhhhhhh. I thought the list had to correspond to the number of ticks, not the length of the dataframe itself. That worked!!! Thank you so much!